# Exclude 1 directory while checking for modifications with SilkSVN

Tags: svn, command-line, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to write a script (commandline or Powershell or ...) which will allow me to check if there were files modified without being checked in...

We have set-up a website and we've been using SVN Turtoise as a SVN client. My script should run every x-houre and check if any file had been modified on the server without it being checked in into SVN. Those modified files should be listed into a txt-file (and if possible it should send an email to notify someone there were modified files).

For now I have the very limited script:

> svn status -q > modified_files.txt

and this does exactly what I want.
BUT, there is one directory which contains logs and user-uploaded content, so that folder shouldn't be checked for modifications. How can I do this with SilK?

Answer (score 2):

1. If your site is Working Copy (it seems so, because status command work), why you care about modified files? Just commit!
2. If this folder is also under Version Control - you do Bad Thing (tm). Just exclude this folder from version control and use the same `svn status -q` as before (but see p.1)
3. You can (on site WC) add **all files and dirs except Upload folder** into changelist and use status command with `--changelist` option

PS: remake your team workflow, which will exclude modification files directly on site and will use only "update from repo by hook" method, will be preferred way of solving problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm well aware of the workflow, but it's not like you think. The site is done, but recently we experienced a hacker attack and now, we want the script to check if files were modified so the script can notify us when an other attack has taken place... You see what I mean?
I like the sound of `--changelist`, is there any documentation you know of?

Comment: @Michiel - only [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.changelists.html) and helps of commands. BTW, if your server OS is "Good OS", you can filter out unwanted output of status inside checker: `svn st -q | grep -v DIRNAME`